# Help with a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to figure what is wrong in this circuit.

There is an ultrasonic module that creates mist from water. 
I measured the tapped inductor and it seems to be fine. Also the resistor is fine. I measured the capacitor and it is 1000pf (I removed it from the board.) I am not sure if the capacitor is faulty but I don't know what it should be. When I measure with my multimeter A - B I get 5V. Also when I measure A-C I also get 5V. When I measure +Module and -Module (I missplaced the + and - on the picture, there are opposite) I get 0V.

Question. Should I be able to read something with a multimeter?

The white lines are how they are connected.

I am not 100% sure that the module is working. My guess is that since it doesn't get any voltage it shouldn't work. I also show you the other side.

[image: Circuit]

[image: Other side]

Comment: Where is the circuit???

Comment: the direct connection between the top of the 47 k ohm resistor and ground is questionable ... the picture shows a discontinuity between the resistor and pin 16 of the IC

Comment: @LeonHeller The picture shows a print **circuit** board, doens't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of voltage may be because it is high frequency AC.

Soldering or wires (original) is terrible.
Check that plated through holes to wires from tracks is complete - this MAY have been marginal and failed.

Trace tracks from pin X to pin Y or solder points and then use ohm-meter to check there is continuity. eg connection to 47k that jsotola mentioned.

If it was working and now isn't then failure of the piezo element seems most likely, and next the IC itself.

Check that the wires are continuous from PCBA to piezo contacts.

ABC is (probably) a transistor - FET or bipolar.
C is gate/base.
B is source / emitter.
A is drain / collector.
There should be AC drive to C
(and, as you report, DC feed of power supply to A via inductor.)
Ab and AC = 5V is close enough to right).

Comment: Thanks for the answer